# Бот не удаляет сообщения с медиаконтентом

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет.

Хочу сделать так, чтобы бот удалял из телеграм-чата репосты из определенного канала. В общем, проблем с удалением текстовых сообщений не возникло, все работает успешно.
Но если репостить сообщения, где есть что-то, кроме текста (фото, видео), то ничего вообще не происходит. И в консоли нет никаких ошибок.
Очень прошу подсказать пути решения проблемы.

Вот код кусок кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def new_message_handler(message):
    if message.forward_from_chat.id == channel_id:
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Message deleted')
```

Answer (score 1):

Исправил обработчик и все заработало. Вопрос закрыт

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text", "photo", "video", "document", "video_note", "voice"])
```